# Get the last instance of a collection using XMLGET

Tags: xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having this XML and I'm looking for a way to get only the value from the last employee using XMLGET Snowflake but I'm not sure how to dynamically calculate the index of the last employee

```
    <dept>
       <employee>
         <value>1</value>
       </employee>
       <employee>
         <value>2</value>
       </employee>
       <employee>
         <value>3</value>
       </employee>
   </dept>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data has employee number in increasing order then can try max function:

```
select max(get(xmlget(col1,'employee'),'$')) from xml_sample;
```

If there is another attribute on basis of which you can fetch the last value then can try using `last_value` function on that attribute.

Comment: Sorry but this is not going to help, I'm looking for something like the xpath function last(), I can't guarantee there is going to be a logic identifier. But I always need to get the values from the last collection